# Zlib decompression method warning using ios 64bit Architecture

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit, zlib

I am just updating one of my applications and I have an error with my decompression method.

This is the warning I am experiencing

```
Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'unit' (aka 'unsigned int')
```

this is the line of code its happening on

```
stream.avail_in = len - stream.total_in;
```

And this is what the whole method looks like

```
#pragma mark - ZLib Compression Methods
//  Returns the decompressed version if the zlib compressed input data or nil if there was an error
- (NSData*) dataByDecompressingData:(NSData*)data {

     NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)data.length);

    Byte* bytes = (Byte*)[data bytes];
    NSInteger len = [data length];
    NSMutableData *decompressedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:COMPRESSION_BLOCK];
    Byte* decompressedBytes = (Byte*) malloc(COMPRESSION_BLOCK);

    z_stream stream;
    int err;
    stream.zalloc = (alloc_func)0;
    stream.zfree = (free_func)0;
    stream.opaque = (voidpf)0;

    stream.next_in = bytes;
    err = inflateInit(&stream);
    CHECK_ERR(err, @"inflateInit");

    while (true) {
        stream.avail_in = len - stream.total_in;
        stream.next_out = decompressedBytes;
        stream.avail_out = COMPRESSION_BLOCK;
        err = inflate(&stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
        [decompressedData appendBytes:decompressedBytes length:(stream.total_out-[decompressedData length])];
        if(err == Z_STREAM_END)
            break;
        CHECK_ERR(err, @"inflate");
    }

    err = inflateEnd(&stream);
    CHECK_ERR(err, @"inflateEnd");

    free(decompressedBytes);
    return decompressedData;
}
```

Comment: warning != error (although it *might* be an indicator) - but .. does it "work"?

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should not use `stream.total_in`.  It may or may not be a large enough type for your application.  It is always `unsigned long`.  Use your own total input counter sized for your application and ignore `stream.total_in`.

Second, I'm guessing that your `CHECK_ERR()` aborts somehow.  You should not abort in the event of a `Z_BUF_ERROR`.  In that case, you can continue by simply providing more input and/or more output space.

Third, the problem here is that you need to pick a `stream.avail_in` that is assured to fit in `unsigned`.  You should be comparing the amount of remaining input to the largest value of `unsigned`, e.g. `UINT_MAX` or `(unsigned)0 - 1`.  If the remaining data is larger, use the max value and deduct that from the remaining input.  If smaller or equal, use all of it and set the remaining input to zero.